# ValidatorCalloutExtender not working in Asp.net Ajax

Tags: asp.net

I have a RadioButtonList with Yes and No Option.Upon clicking the Yes button,Textbox1 and TextBox2 will be displayed and clicking No button Textbox3 and Textbox4 will be displayed.All the above the textboxes have ValidatorCalloutExtender.Upon clicking the  Submit Button, the ValidatorCalloutExtender is not popup.Can any please help me..

Here is the code sample:

```
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvENo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1"
                                Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please Enter ENo!" ValidationGroup="Agent" />
                            <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender10" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                TargetControlID="rfvENo">
                            </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct ValidationGroup="Agent" set on the submit button? Your code is working fine for me otherwise.

Comment: I have set ValidationGroup="Agent" on the Submit Button.But it is still not working..

Answer (score 0):

It requires a class to work

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddCubicFeet" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddCubicFeet"      Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage='<br/>Enter the total cubic feet.' ValidationGroup="vgAdd" Enabled="False"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender9" runat="server" HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" TargetControlID="rfvAddCubicFeet"></cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```